# How do you execute a method at application start in xcode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm an Xcode newbie, and I know it's kind of a stupid question, however I haven't found anything on the matter (maybe wrong search parameters).

Anyway, here's the problem: How do you run a method at application start/end?

Details: I'm making a flashlight app with a button that turns the LED on/off and changes the title of the button("Turn flash on"/"Turn flash off");

Everything is ok, but when I exit the app(home button) while the flash is on and run the app again, it keeps the settings from the last run(button title is "Turn flash off" and the ison BOOL stays YES);

So, how do I fix that?
I tried making a method `'changetitle: (NSString *)text'` and placing it in `'dealloc'`,  `'viewDidLoad'`,`'viewDidUnload'` but they only work when app has a 'fresh' run (closed from multitasking = twice home button and quit there), so it's useless.
Do I need to call the method from main? It seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

```
– applicationDidBecomeActive:
– applicationWillResignActive:
– applicationDidEnterBackground:
– applicationWillEnterForeground:
– applicationWillTerminate:
```

These are the methods you looking for.

On Ross Alexander suggestion:

```
   – application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
   – applicationDidFinishLaunching:
```

Comment: applicationDIdFinishLaunching (at start of the app as well) +1 to comment was writing these out as it was posted.

Comment: He has put his functionality in view did load in view controller. That is why I don't add the applicationDidFinishLaunching

Comment: Yep noticed that, always good to have alternatives, especially as a newbie :P

Answer (score 2):

With the advent of iOS4, all our apps have to deal with multitasking whether we like it or not.  In previous versions of the sdk, your app would just terminate when the user pressed the home button, but now, it's relegated to the background (thus, keeping it's state).

You can reset the apps state through delegate methods, but it sounds like you just want to terminate it.

To do so, head over to your apps *-Info.plist and add a new row at the bottom.  Select the key, "Application does not run in the background" and set the value as "YES".  Now, it will shutdown when the user presses home.

You can read more over here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/CoreApplication/CoreApplication.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH3-SW1

Comment: Great answer. But I suggest rather than "relegated to the background" use "suspended". The "background" state is when you app is actually running (doing GPS, downloading etc..). The "suspended" state is the correct term for what you are talking about.

Comment: Really great alternative. Thanks a lot for that. I do, however, have to learn how to deal with the delegates and multitasking for other apps(this is my second one...after 'hello world');

Answer (score -2):

Look at UIApplicationDelegate http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html This should help guide you in the right direction.